# Mix color between red and white in GLSL

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I would like to mix with fading between base color and ghost color
base color is white, ghost color is red now it fades to black, not to white(mixed with red)

I have base color as white, ghost color as red, and diffuse color which depends on the light direction ( dot product of normal and camera position)

```
#version 100
precision highp int;
precision highp float;

uniform float time;
uniform float line;
uniform float fadingTime;
uniform vec4 ghostColor;
uniform vec4 baseColor;
uniform float edgeIntensity;



varying float  lightDiffuse;

void main()
{

    float rampLight =lightDiffuse;

    float light = (1.0 - rampLight) * 0.9;
    vec4 lightColor = vec4(ghostColor.r, ghostColor.g, ghostColor.b, ghostColor.a);
    vec4 diffuseColor = lightColor*light;
    float sintime = clamp(abs(cos(time*fadingTime)), 0.0, 1.0);    

    float edgeIntens = edgeIntensity;
    edgeIntens*= sintime;
    vec4 smootheddiffuseColor = smoothstep(baseColor, vec4(lightColor), vec4(edgeIntens));

    vec4 mixeddiffuseColor = mix(baseColor, diffuseColor, vec4(smootheddiffuseColor));

    gl_FragColor = mixeddiffuseColor;

}
```

Comment: it mixed between white and red, but with no transparency due to missing diffuse light in the calculation.. and it fades to full white, which I don't want, I need to fade to ( a mix ) of white and red

Comment: @Rabbid76 Do you have any suggestion ?